Logical replication security risk with run_as_owner = false
The docs say

If the subscription has been configured with run_as_owner = true, then no user switching will occur. Instead, all operations will be performed with the permissions of the subscription owner. In this case, the subscription owner only needs privileges to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE from the target table, and does not need privileges to SET ROLE to the table owner. However, this also means that any user who owns a table into which replication is happening can execute arbitrary code with the privileges of the subscription owner. For example, they could do this by simply attaching a trigger to one of the tables which they own. Because it is usually undesirable to allow one role to freely assume the privileges of another, this option should be avoided unless user security within the database is of no concern.

I'm not sure I understand why that's a security risk. Isn't it always the case that the table owner can force code execution on roles that use their table? My naive intuition is that the table owner is a sensitive role precisely because it has those privileges, whereas the subscription owner role can have very restrictive privileges (just CRUD on its tables) Why is that intuition wrong?

The risk is the other way around. If you are an unprivileged user and own a table to which data are replicated by the subscription, you could create a trigger on that table and define it as a replica trigger. Then when the logical replication apply worker executes a DML statement on your table to apply some changes, your trigger function would be executed in the context of the subscription owner. That means that you, the unprivileged table owner, can make the privileged user that owns the subscription execute any code that you like.

Ah I see. The subscription owner is privileged because it can modify the subscription itself, and also access the upstream DB. Is that the rationale?

If you are using run_as_owner, then the subscription owner must at least have the privileges to modify all subscribed tables. Very often, it is a superuser. If the subscription owner has no more rights than the table owner, there is not much risk.
